# How to express this in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

must be **true**

```
kword_search = "void main(){"  
kword_search = " void main(){"
kword_search = "void  main (){"
kword_search = " void main ( ){"
```

what i've done so far:

```
/\s*void\s+main\s*(\s*)$/.test(kword_search)
```

The problem here kword_search = "void main" returns true with the condition i wrote. I want to do get inside a condition when the looping char is in the '{' position

Comment: Escape the `(` and `)` - they're special regex characters too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must escape the parenthesis :

```
/\s*void\s+main\s*\(\s*\)$/.test(kword_search)
```

But with the $ at the end, it won't accept the {, so you probably want

```
/\s*void\s+main\s*\(\s*\)\s*{$/.test(kword_search)
```

Comment: @dystroy. Thanks i've missed that ^^

Comment: i forgot to get back to it sorry men